# Debugger in class method ends up in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-debug

I have a controller with a action similar to this

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

    ....

    def test
      Events.first.test
    end

    ....

end
```

and a model similar to this

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

....

    def test
        debugger
    end

....

end
```

What confuses me is that, when the action is triggered and calls the method of the model wich then brings me the debugger, I am not in the method of the model.

the debuggers **list** command brings me this

```
(rdb:73) list
[1327, 1336] in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/base.rb
   1327        end
   1328  
   1329        def perform_action
   1330          if action_methods.include?(action_name)
   1331            send(action_name)
=> 1332            default_render unless performed?
   1333          elsif respond_to? :method_missing
   1334            method_missing action_name
   1335            default_render unless performed?
   1336          else
```

and **self** is not an instance of the Even class

```
(rdb:73) self
#<EventsController:0x1032786d0 @performed_render=false, @_headers={"Cache-Control"=>"
....
```

Am I missing the something? How do I get the debugger into the test method of the Event class?

Comment: Since [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) 1.6.0, this should work out of the box. Salute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's with implicit return in last line.

Add some line after your debugger like

```
    def test
        debugger
        puts 'debug'
    end
```